# Trouble accessing a value from a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following dictionary

```
Dict = {'Manu':{u'ID0020879.07': [{'ID': u'ID0020879.07', 'log': u'log-123-56', 'owner': [Manu], 'item': u'WRAITH', 'main_id': 5013L, 'status': u'noticed', 'serial': u'89980'}]}}
```

How can I access the serial from this dictionary? 
I tried `Dict['Manu']['serial']`, But its not working as expected..
Guys any idea?

Comment: Also `Dict['Manu']` doesn't have the key `'serial'`...

Comment: Did you go through any dictionary tutorials?

Comment: As a partial tip, hit 'reformat code' in your favorite IDE to show the structure of your dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your dictionary is very nested one.Try like this.

```
In [1]: Dict['Manu']['ID0020879.07'][0]['serial']
Out[1]: u'89980'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the restructured dictionary.

```
{
    'Manu': {
        u'ID0020879.07': [{
            'ID': u'ID0020879.07',
            'log': u'log-123-56',
            'owner': [Manu],
            'item': u'WRAITH',
            'main_id': 5013L,
            'status': u'noticed',
            'serial': u'89980'
        }]
    }
}
```

Now, you can see where the serial key is located more clearly (not under Manu)...

It is instead

```
Dict['Manu']['ID0020879.07'][0]['serial']
```

I suggest you fix that data source to not make `ID0020879.07` a key of the data (because it is duplicated in the ID key of that object in the list).

Perhaps fix like so where the Manu key maps to a list of "accounts", each with an ID and other fields

```
{
    'Manu': [{
        'ID': u'ID0020879.07',
        'log': u'log-123-56',
        'owner': [Manu],
        'item': u 'WRAITH',
        'main_id': 5013L,
        'status': u'noticed',
        'serial': u'89980'
    }]
}
```

And then you could do

```
Dict['Manu'][0]['serial']
```

Or loop the list to get all the serial keys

```
for item in Dict['Manu']:
    print(item['serial'])
```